# python imaging library cannot save PNG to JPG

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I installed PIL 1.1.7 from source on Mac OSX.
I also installed required libraries from Macports.
Using python 2.6.

After installing PIL, I could successfully run the selftest.py (all tests pass)

But when I try running the following code, I find that I am not able to convert PNG to JPG. I am however able to convert PNG to GIF, PNG to PPM. I can also read JPGs.

```
import os
import sys 
import Image

for infile in sys.argv[1:]:
    f, e = os.path.splitext(infile)
    outfile = f + ".jpg"
    print outfile
    if infile != outfile:
        try:
            Image.open(infile).save(outfile, 'jpg') #Note: gif or ppm works
        except IOError:
            print "cannot convert", infile
            if os.path.exists(outfile):
               print 'cleaning up...'
               os.remove(outfile)
```

** update with stack trace. Looks like encoder is missing. I did however install libjpeg thru macport.

Cleaning up...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_to_jpeg.py", line 15, in <module>
    Image.open(infile).save(outfile, 'jpeg')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 471, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 495, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 401, in _getencoder
    raise IOError("encoder %s not available" % encoder_name)
IOError: encoder jpeg not available
```

Comment: Please, post the exception stacktrace here

Comment: Remove all traces of macports and install hombrew.

Comment: @jterrace Thanks for the suggestion. Let me try.

Answer (score 4):

Use `jpeg` not `jpg` for the format identifier.

Comment: @sunnybythesea Oh sorry. I tried your code and it worked when I made that change. Can you post the stacktrace in your question? Your code works for me so without more information I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: I've updated with the trace. Looks like encoder is missing. I'm going to try homebrew.

Comment: im = Image.open("qsl.jpg")
 draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
 draw.line((0, 0) + im.size, fill=128)
 draw.line((0, im.size[1], im.size[0], 0), fill=128)
 # get a font
 #Fonts generated for a Mac using
 #mkdir fonts && cd fonts
 #fondu /System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.dfont
 #cp * /Users/tim/pe35/lib/python3.5/site-packages
 fnt = ImageFont.truetype('Courier', 300)
 draw.text((100, 300), "Hello", font=fnt, fill=(255, 255, 255, 128))
 draw.text((100, 1300), "World", font=fnt, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255)
 im.save("new.jpg", "jpeg")

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @jterrace for suggesting homebrew.

Solution:

```
Install homebrew 
brew install python 
brew install pil
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have to take some additional steps to work with JPG with PIL on Mac OSX.

I've found some links, but nothing you couldn't also find on google:

http://websaucesoftware.com/uncategorized/getting-pil-installed-on-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-with-jpeg-support

http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/11/16/pil-libjpeg-jpeg-and-mac-osx-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 1):

You are playing my song.

I wrestled with JPEG support in PIL for weeks before I landed on this link: http://proteus-tech.com/blog/cwt/install-pil-in-snow-leopard/

It's the only thing that worked. The gory details of my un-installation and re-installation process are here: http://www.thetoryparty.com/2010/08/31/pil-on-snow-leopard-_jpeg_resync_to_restart-error/

The summary of what I did:

1) Force the gcc and gcov paths to 4.2 (they had been set to 4.0 to get MySQLdb to install)

2) In my .profile, commented out certain ARCHFLAGS lines I had kicking around (possibly optional step?)

3) Picked through my system to delete EVERYTHING called anything like “libjpeg,” “PIL” or “Imaging" -- to clean house

4) Followed the steps at the above proteus-tech link, starting from downloading a fresh libjpeg.

Good luck! You can do it!

(P.S.: Note that if you WERE getting an error from selftest.py -- specifically "IOError: decoding error when reading image file" -- and you WEREN'T able to load a JPEG, then this is the process that solved THAT problem:

http://www.thetoryparty.com/2011/04/07/pil-and-jpeg-decoding-error-the-revenge/ It may be of interest if you run into more trouble later.

Note both problems pertain to libjpeg needing to be built with "-arch i386" and not "-arch x86_64." So that's the fun of 64 bit for you!)

Comment: thanks @Tory I ended up using homebrew which solved the isssue. I had to install python from homebrew first though, and then PIL.